# SSIS with Salesforce

Tags: integration, sqlserver

I have a requirement where in we need to push data from sql server to Salesforce on daily basis. Can anybody suggest me the best possible way to do the same ?

Also After googling things, it seems like the only possible way for this kind of setup is to purchase a connector (not sure) however we are thinking of setting this up on our own and keeping the third party softwares as our last option. So are they any docs to start with.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Salesforce method for such a connection is through Salesforce Connect. You can find information about that here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=salesforce_connect.htm&type=5.

Another Salesforce offering is the Data Loader. This can be scheduled to import data into Salesforce. You can find the guide for Data Loader here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/data_loader.htm

If you're looking for something more bespoke, I suggest you look into the APIs that are available for Salesforce. You can find all of the developer documentation here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/.

I would focus first on the Bulk 2.0 and Bulk API Developer Guides. Then I would look at the REST API Developer Guide and the SOAP API Developer Guide.